# Unity and Github Scene Merging

Tags: git, unity-game-engine, github

So my team has been running into a problem with GitHub and Unity. Whenever we try to merge branches our scene gets screwed up, everything in the scene gets deleted and overall it causes problems. Were trying to look for a better way to do this. Does anyone who has experience working in big teams know how to solve this? Like a workflow or process of moving work into the main branch that can solve this problem? Anything will help!

Comment: Ok sorry, my mistake. This is my first post on StackOverflow

Comment: Understood. Welcome! I'm not very experienced with Unity, but it's probably worth covering more details about how your scene gets screwed up, etc.

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SmartMerge.html can help but in general it is a trainwreck. Figure out how to split up your work so you're not all working in the same scene.

Comment: Use prefabs! This way you don't even have to touch the scene too much ;)

Answer (score 3):

The way I've been able to successfully work with GitHub in a team is to make *everything* a prefab. To clarify, I looked at my hierarchy top level, and tried to make everything there a separate prefab. e.g.

```
root
.Camera Items
.Game Manager Items
.Level Game Objects
```

By separating areas of concern into separate prefabs, you can modify the prefab, which is saved as an asset, and the actual Scene itself isn't modified.

To break it down, if your scene is made up of the three items listed above, then it doesn't matter how much you modify your specific prefabs, the scene is STILL just made up of the three prefabs. The scene doesn't store the prefab details, just a reference to the prefab.

So, Person A can be working on the Game Manager prefab, and Person B can be working on the Level Game Objects prefab, and when it comes time to commit, the scene itself hasn't changed.

The one point is that the prefab overrides **ARE** saved in the scene, so, to make things easier, we simply made sure our prefabs were completely saved before committing.

It's not easy to get into the swing of it, but when you do, it's workable. Not great, but workable.